# An irreducible polynomial

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field and $f\in k[x_0,x_1,y_0,y_1,y_2]$ be given by $$f(x_0,x_1,y_0,y_1,y_2)=y_0x_0^2+y_1x_0x_1+y_2x_1^2.$$ Why is $f$ irreducible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that $f(x_0,x_1,y_0,y_1,y_2)$ is homogeneous of degree $2$ w.r.t. the set of indeterminates $\{x_0,x_1\}$, and homogeneous linear w.r.t. $\{y_0,y_1,y_2\}$.

So it suffices to show the  de-homogenised polynomial is irreducible:
$$F(X, Y_1,Y_2)=1+Y_1X+Y_2X^2 \qquad(X=\frac{x_1}{x_0},\;Y_1=\frac{y_1}{y_0},\;Y_2=\frac{y_2}{y_0}) $$
Can you take it from here?

Comment: Also look at Bernard's answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1394545/irreducibility-criteria-for-polynomials-with-several-variables).